# Having Trouble Debugging Possible Rcpp Memory Leak

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am writing an R package using RcppEigen called [RcppCoDA](https://github.com/jsilve24/RcppCoDA)

I think there may be a memory leak somewhere in my project but I am not sure. I am unfortunately having trouble running Valgrind as it seems it may not support the OS X Mojave and I am running into errors detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373903/valgrind-r-is-not-working-fatal-error-cannot-create-r-tempdir).

I think it should be pretty easy to reproduce the error:

```
library(RcppCoDA) # devtools::install_github("jsilve24/RcppCoDA")
library(microbenchmark)

d <- c(100,1000)
X <- matrix(abs(rnorm(prod(d))), d[1], d[2])
X <- clo(X)

# This runs fine
z <- RcppCoDA::alr(X, d=4)

# This for some reason takes forever to run... I think this might be a bug
for (i in 1:1000){
  z <- RcppCoDA::alr(X, d=4)  
}


# This causes RStudio to crash... or takes forever to run...
microbenchmark(
  RcppCoDA::alr(X, d=4), times=10
)
```

I have reread the code over and over and don't see how I could be having memory errors unless I am just misusing Rcpp somehow... Unfortunately, as I can't seem to get Valgrind to work [as outlined here](http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/05/debugging-with-valgrind/) I am really at a loss for how to debug. I am not even sure if there is a bug in my code or somewhere else.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Install Docker on macOS.  Debug in a container. Or get a Linux shell another way. There is a reason these tools are emphasized in _Writing R Extensions_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have never used docker before. I think they are images that you spin-up right? Is there one you could point me to that has the required setup to run valgrind etc...?

Comment: You can try `rhub::check_with_valgrind()`. If that gives you something useful, you can make use of that particular Docker container also locally.

Comment: Some help for setting up docker on mac for R package development: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2019-August/078269.html

Comment: Which I'll turn into a blog post given that I wrote most of it over email :)   That was a easy case though as Roger only needed gfortran-9. Yet here `apt-get install valgrind` is no more complicated ....

Comment: That blog is now up at http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2019/08/05#023_rocker_debug_example

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to some helpful comments I was able to get Valgrind working in a docker image.

Just an outline of how I did it:

1. I used the docker image: [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/)
2. Start-up the image/container: `docker run rocker/rstudio`
3. With that running: In a separate terminal: `docker ps`
4. Grab the container ID of the running image and then run: `docker exec -it <containerID> bash`
5. Install valgrind and a number of other things required by devtools
6. Run R with valgrind debug: `R -d "valgrind --leak-check=full"`
7. Run whatever code is causing errors and evaluate valgrind output.

Thank you for the help!